# scss not applying throwing error

Tags: reactjs

I am using webpack 2 and node 6.9 and trying to implement the css/scss in my project. I have installed all the required loaders like style,sass etc. earlier below was my webpack configuration and it is working fine but scss is not applied on my project,

```
rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                cacheDirectory: true
            }
        }]
```

to apply the css i have installed all the loaders and i changed the above webpack configuration to below

```
rules: [{
           test: /\.scss$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
  loader: [
    'css-loader',
    'babel-loader',
    'postcss',
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      query: {
        sourceMap: false,
        presets: ['es2015'],
      }
    }
  ],
})
        }]
    };
    plugins: [
new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css"),
  ]
```

but it is still not working for me. i have tried some other configurations also but everytime it is giving me same error as below,

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: \index.js Unexpected token (7:3)
 You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

ReactDOM.render((
 <App />
), document.getElementById('root'));
at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap 6298272…:708)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6298272…:659)
at bootstrap 6298272…:708
at bootstrap 6298272…:708
```

Can anyone help me to get rid of the error and apply the scss. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Able to make it work. **Below is the code:**

```
rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: [ "style-loader", "css-loader", 'sass-loader' ],
        }]
```